# When is $n^2+n+p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behaviour of Polynomials in a PID!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/behaviour-of-polynomials-in-a-pid)

Prove: if $p$ is a prime, and if $n^2+n+p$ is prime for $0\leq n \leq \sqrt{p/3}$, then it is also prime for $0 \leq n \leq p-2$.

This appeared on reddit recently, but no proof was posted. With $p=41$, it is Euler's famous prime-generating polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows by employing in [Rabinowitsch's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590) proof a Gauss bound, e.g. see Theorem 9.1 [here](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ant-st.pdf#page=18).

Comment: I should have searched more carefully. Thank you!