# Can a polynomial return only prime numbers?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

I recently learned about The polynomial $p(n)=n^2-n+41$, and how for $1\le n\le40, n\in\mathbb Z$, $p(n)$ is prime. I understand that primes are very difficult to find, so from that I can conclude that we haven't found a polynomial $q(m)$ where $m\in\mathbb N$ with no upper bound is prime, but is it proven that no such polynomial exists?

Comment: what if the constant is $0$?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2590/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670070/242)

Comment: As I said under my answer, when it got talked about it doesn't work for constant polynomials.

Comment: Actually - I'm going to retract my comment. I assumed the coefficients were integers and I missed a few special cases. So none of what I've said applies.

Comment: The title asks about polynomials which "return" **only** prime numbers. The body seems to be asking a different question, about "a polynomial $q(m)$ where $m\in\mathbb N$ with no upper bound is prime", i.e., whether there are polynomials which "return" (to use your jargon) **infinitely many** prime values; there are probably lots of those, but the only proven examples are polynomials of degree one.

Comment: I think the questioned asked is entirely different than the title and the cited previous answer.  The title asks for a polynomial that only returns primes.  But the question asked asks for a polynomial with no upper limit of prime values. (Which if such existed would *NOT* help the discovery of primes in any way).

Answer (score 2):

No. This is because of things like, $f(c)-f(0)= ac^n+\ldots+c$ has all terms divisible by c. In general, $f(f(d)+d)-f(d)$ will divide by f(d). Even more generally $f(k\cdot f(d)+d)$ should also divide by d.

Comment: That doesn't show $f(n)$ isn't prime?

Comment: @Shuri2060 okay you got me. It does for any polynomial not repeating values though.

Comment: Assuming $f(c)\ne c$. this is possible in constant polynomials though.

Comment: Let's simplify the answer. We have n^2 -n +41 =(n-7)(n+6)+42+41=(n-7)(n+6) +83. 83 is prime and n-7 may be divisible by is ,so is x+6 with especial values of x. So this polynomial does not always give primes.

Comment: We, are talking about a general topic, not the specific polynomial.