# Modular Arithmetic Question $p(x)=x^2-x+41$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone give me a hint on this problem please?
Show that the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-x+41$ takes prime values for x in the
set (0,1,2,...,40)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just compute the values.

Comment: There is no cool theoretic way to show that "$p(n)$ is composite $\implies n>40$", as far as I know. Just check the values.

Comment: @Arthur you can at least show all values the polynomial take on are odd etc. just with simple parity arguments.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Checking that $p(1),p(2),\cdots,p(40)$ are all prime, or checking for each prime below $\sqrt{p(40)}$ that they don't divide any $p(n)$. It's still checking, one by one, either way.

Comment: @Arthur my point is if even if more than 1 of them is even we could disprove the claim it's a heuristic argument to use the parity argument.  also just checking 2 and 3 will show if they are in the proper classes mod 6.

Comment: A short proof given in 1913 by Rabinowitz. I gave a proof in simple terms (no fields, just binary quadratic forms) at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357

Comment: @WillJagy That's extremely interesting! Thank you for sharing that!

Comment: This is a fairly immediate consequence of the fact that the ring of integers of $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-163})\,$ isa UFD. For proofs see the links I gave in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2590/242)

Comment: take $$x=41$$ and the number is not prime

Comment: @Dr.S Trivially. But nobody claimed it was prime at $\,x=41\,$ so what is your point?

Comment: ok sorry i have misread this

Answer (score 1):

One relatively low-level approach involves using quadratic residues.  First render $n^2-n+41$ as an odd number.  So if $p|n^2-n+41$ for any prime $p$ then $p$ must be odd.

We then test

$4(n^2-n+41)=(2n-1)^2+163\equiv 0\bmod p$

which will be contradicted whenever $-163$ is a nonquadratic residue $\bmod p$.  If the contradiction holds for all odd $p<41$ then we establish primality for all polynomial values below $41^2$ (thus all nonnegative $n$ below $41$).  There are eleven prime factor candidates to test, but a nonquadratic residue for each one applies simultaneously to all forty-one values of interest.