# Follow up to "Modular Arithmetic Question $p(x)=x^2−x+41$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442147/modular-arithmetic-question-px-x2-x41) is the original question. Aside from simply calculating the values of $p(0)$ through $p(40)$, can anyone suggest how modular arithmetic might be used to show that $p(x)$ returns primes for all values of $x$ in the set $\{0, 1, 2, ..., 40\}$?  For context, this question comes from a relatively introductory math text, though it is marked as a challenging question.

Comment: If we don't want to use brute force, we can do this via some simple modular arithmetic plus the magical fact that $\mathbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-163}}{2}]$ is a unique factorization domain. Proving this fact is hard, though.

Comment: I give an elementary proof of an if and only if version at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/is-the-notorious-n2-n-41-prime-generator-the-last-of-its-type/289357#289357  The original was by Rabinowitz in 1913.

Comment: @MishaLavrov the whole business is fairly easy when written using binary quadratic forms. Of course, that is of no help for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write $x^2 + x + 41.$ Just habit. Same values, note $$ (x+1)^2 - (x+1) + p = x^2 + x + p $$

The statement is this: given a (positive) prime number $p,$ the unary polynomial
$$ x^2 + x + p $$
takes prime values for all integer $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq p-2$ if, and only if, the (positive) binary quadratic form 
$$ x^2 + xy + p y^2 $$
is the only form (up to $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalence) of its discriminant. Checking class number of a discriminant $\Delta$ is a finite computation, we need only consider Gauss reduced forms, meaning
$$ a x^2 + b xy + c y^2   $$
with
$$ b^2 - 4ac = \Delta \; , \; $$
$$ \gcd(a,b,c) = 1 \; , \; $$
$$ |b| \leq a \leq c   $$
IF $a=c,$ then
$$  b \geq 0 $$
IF $|b| = a,$ then
$$  b = a $$

Comment: they asked for $x^2-x+q$